# Lua iterator using an iterator

Tags: lua, iterator

I have a function defined as a C binding that provides a generic `for` iterator:

```lua
for el in doc:each() do ... end
```

I want to write an iterator in Lua that iterates using this function, but return a modification of each result. How can I do this?

---

**Edit**: I'm sure my iterator has to start something like this, but I'm getting lost in the body of the function.

```lua
function myiterator()
   local f, c, v = doc:each()
   return (function(c2, v2)
      -- ??
   end), ??, ??
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function myiterator()
   local generator, state, prev_x = doc:each()

   local function my_generator()
      local x, y = generator(state, prev_x)
      if x ~= nil then
         prev_x = x
         -- modify x, y
         local modified_x = x + 100
         local modified_y = "("..y..")"
         -- modified_x must be non-nil
         return modified_x, modified_y
      end
   end

   return my_generator
end
```

---

**Before:**

```
local doc = {each = function() return ipairs{"aa", "bb", "cc"} end}
for x, y in doc:each() do
   print(x, y)
end
```

Output:

```
1   aa
2   bb
3   cc
```

---

**After:**

```
local doc = {each = function() return ipairs{"aa", "bb", "cc"} end}

-- insert myiterator definition here

for x, y in myiterator() do
   print(x, y) -- now x and y are modified
end
```

Output:

```
101 (aa)
102 (bb)
103 (cc)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This got me where I needed to go. Note that the `each()` I have only returns a single value, which makes the code simpler than what you have.  FWIW I found your usage of `prev_x` and `x` to be a little clunkier than just re-using the same variable each time (per my answer) but perhaps what you have is better as an illustration of what's being used.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how your C function works, but here is an iterator function that should do what you are looking for. It calls an iterator triplet repeatedly, takes the first return value, and calls a function on it to return a new value:

```lua
function map(transformer, f, c, v)
    return function()
        v = f(c, v)
        if v ~= nil then
            return transformer(v)
        end
    end
end
```

For instance, this takes the keys in the table `{ 'a', 'b', 'c' }` and squares them. The second return value (the values corresponding to the keys) is ignored:

```lua
for v in map(function (x) return x * x end, pairs { 'a', 'b', 'c' }) do
    print(v)
end
```

You can do `map(function (elem) return do_something_to(elem) end, doc:each())`.

It's easier to read the `map` function when it's written using a coroutine:

```lua
function map(transformer, f, c, v)
    return coroutine.wrap(function ()
        for val in f, c, v do
            coroutine.yield(transformer(val))
        end
    end)
end
```

For completeness, either of these functions would allow you to use two return values from the original iterator triplet:

```lua
function map2(transformer, f, c, v)
    return function()
        local v2
        v, v2 = f(c, v)
        if v ~= nil then
            return transformer(v, v2)
        end
    end
end

function map(transformer, f, c, v)
    return coroutine.wrap(function ()
        for v, v2 in f, c, v do
            coroutine.yield(transformer(v, v2))
        end
    end)
end

for v in map2(function (a, b) return a .. b end, pairs { 'a', 'b', 'c' }) do
    print(v)
end
-- This prints out:
-- 1a
-- 2b
-- 3c
```

Comment: I like the 'clever' way you use the multiple return values from the original iterator and catch them as `f, c, v` in the map. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the iterator into a coroutine, see also https://www.lua.org/pil/9.3.html

```lua
-- dummy object
local doc = {
    each = function()
        return pairs{ 11, 22, 33 }
    end
}

local myiterator = coroutine.wrap(function()
    local f, c, v = doc:each()
    return f, c, v
end)

for f, c, v in myiterator() do
    print(f, c, v)
end
```

```
$ lua test.lua
1   11  nil
2   22  nil
3   33  nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those that helped. I learned that my iterator function does not HAVE to return 2 or 3 values. This is a valid list-table iterator:

```lua
function every(list)
   local i=0
   return function() -- no arguments used!
      i = i+1
      return list[i]
   end
end

for word in every{'foo', 'bar', 'jim'} do print(word) end
--> foo
--> bar
--> jim
```

Because `every()` does not return a second value (the "invariant" value), a `nil` is passed as the first parameter to the anonymous function on each iteration. The second value passed to that anonymous function is the value returned from the function on a previous pass (or the third return value from `every()` on the very first pass)...but if that does not help us iterate, we don't need to use it.

Because none of the answers so far exactly answered what I needed, here is the solution I ended up with:

```lua
function myiterator()
   local f, c, v = doc:each()
   return function()
      v = f(c,v)
      if v then
         -- NOTE: Do NOT change the `v` variable here, because
         -- f() may expect it to be exactly what it returned
         -- in order to iterator properly on the next invocation.
         local myvalue = mutate(v)
         return myvalue
      end
   end
end
```